# Baked Procedural Texture Does Not Match Cycles Render

Tags: baking

I am trying to bake geometry information into a texture (Curve, Edge, Crevice, AO and Cavity) into a single RGB Texture. My shader multiplies the esults by each colo and then adds them together for final result. Cycles render in viewport looks amazing and absolutely correct. Baked texture result is completely incorrect color wise, and also seems to not be mapping properly to UV asI can see hard edges with drastic color changes where there should not be hard edges.

This is a screenshot of Cycles Viewport Render
[image: Cycles Viewport Render]

This is a screenshot using Evee and the baked texture
[image: Baked Texture]

This is the image node for baked texture
[image: Image Node]

And this is the Bake settings
[image]

This is my Shader Setup
[image]

Comment: Hello ! You shouldn't set the image texture to "Non-Color" for color data, try setting it to sRGB. The texture density depends on the size of your image so if you don't like the precision, you should try with a higher res image

Comment: This is not a color texture, the texture represent mask information, so it should be set to non-color. I thought perhaps the texture res was the cause but it is not, same result regardless of textureresolution